# wampserver speed optimization

Tags: performance, wampserver

i have an application that reads data of a WampServer database,  the whole setup works well, and i have been able to connect the server and user, i edited my etc hosts folder by adding the ap of the router., i increased the max_execution_time to 200, max_file_size to 500, post file size to 500.
This is my problem so far...
i was able to import 29000 patients record to the wampserver, when the application tries to read the record from the wampServer, it takes from 2-5 mins to popop,, i have a limited time frame,,, and was wondering if this can be fixed, to a matter of seconds. thanks

Comment: @deadfiligreti Welcome to SO! Please edit your question to show us the existing code giving you problems and clarify your question.

Comment: it is a ms windows server application that reads database of wamp server..in one of the file lies a 23,000 patient record tat takes about 2-3 minutes for it to display on the application screen....Ive tried various methods, and any help would be greatly apprecaited